# Liquibase behaves different with utf8 from 3.4 to 3.5?

Tags: utf-8, liquibase

we have utf8 sql files and using liquibase. I was setting up liquibase from ground up and had issues with utf8 encoded sql files for mysql.

I set everything from env variable to mysql connection string to guarante to use utf8 encoding but nothing worked. Tipps i tried: Setting env like file.encoding, setting utf8 into the connection string for mysql connection, setting the encoding for the database, client and server.

What worked was switching from Liquibase 3.5.1 to 3.4.2.

Did something change the behaviour or does Liquibase 3.5.1 has a new/different behaviour on how to handle utf8 files properly?

Example Error message when i use 3.5.1 instead of 3.4.2 (nothing else is different):
"Unexpected error running Liquibase: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO " ...

Comment: What kind of issues? What goes wrong how?

Comment: It might depend on the jre you are using. Are you sure you used the same for both versions?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The utf8 sql file didn't work. MySql was complaining about lexical issue and/or problem with the statement. Problem where utf8 characters.

Comment: @Jens switched the Liquibase version and than it worked. So whatever the problem between those two versions are, they show this issue with the default-jre debian package.

Comment: Can you show the  exact  error messages?

Comment: @sigi I once analyzed the encoding thing in liquibase and remember that it actually uses whatever the jre was set to. So it was just an idea. I don't know if something was changed between those versions. But you should edit your question and show the real error message (and stacktrace). Then it would be much easier to check the liquibase code for changes. (Turn on debug mode for the logs.)

Comment: bug fixed - https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2843

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sigi I may have encountered the same issue starting version 3.5.0 (3.5.1)

Token errors suggest that it must have to with the Lexical analysis added in version 3.5

https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues/CORE-2843

**Fixed in version 3.5.2**

```
SimpleSqlGrammer.jj
S_CHAR_LITERAL didn't support the escaped single quote within a string literal \'
```

quick workaround would be to replace escaped single quote **\'** with two quotes **''** which is also working well in MySQL string literals